# SQL - How to GROUP BY

Tags: sql, database

```
/*Displays employees’ last names and the Job Title and GROUP Job Title*/

USE [EXAMPLEDB]
SELECT empLName
FROM tblEmployee
```

Here is where I get confused, how do I do this using two different tables that contain the employee last name and the other the employee job title?

```
SELECT jobTitle
FROM tblJobTitle 
GROUP BY jobTitle
```

These are my tables:

```
--This Code Creates the Job Title Table--

CREATE TABLE [SHATTKudlerFineFoods].dbo.tblJobTitle
(
jobJobID varchar (4) CONSTRAINT PK_jobJobID PRIMARY KEY Not Null,
jobJobClass varchar (60) Not Null,
jobTitle varchar (60) Not Null,
jobDescription varchar (300) Not Null,
jobStatus varchar (11) Not Null
)

--This Code Creates the Employee Table--

CREATE TABLE [SHATTKudlerFineFoods].dbo.tblEmployee
(
empEmpID varchar (3) CONSTRAINT PK_empEmployeeID PRIMARY KEY Not Null,
empLName varchar (20) Not Null,
empFName varchar (15) Not Null,
empAddress varchar (30) Not Null,
empCity varchar (20) Not Null,
empState varchar (2) Not Null,
empZIPCode varchar (5) Not Null,
empAreaCode varchar (3) Not Null,
empPhoneNo varchar (8) Not Null,
empGender varchar (1) Not Null,
empDOB smalldatetime Not Null,
empAge Tinyint Not Null,
empHireDate smalldatetime Not Null,
empNoOfExempt Tinyint Not Null,
empMaritalStatus varchar (3) Not Null,
empSalary money Not Null,
empStoreID varchar (4) CONSTRAINT FK_strStoreID FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES
tblStores(strStoreID) Not Null,
empJobID varchar (4) CONSTRAINT FK_jobJobID FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES 
tblJobTitle(jobJobID) Not Null
)
```

Comment: You will need to use a join to get the data from more than 1 table.  If you need to have all the employees' names for each job title you will have to use GROUP_CONCAT (in mysql, but not part of standard sql)

Comment: Nothing to do with the answer but..Instead of `GROUP BY`, you can use `DISTINCT`... `GROUP BY` is more suitable for aggregations

Answer (score 5):

You should `JOIN` the tables:

```
SELECT jobTitle 
FROM tblJobTitle jt
INNER JOIN tblEmployee e on e.JobID = jt.ID
GROUP BY jobTitle
```

`JobID` is a column in `tblEmployee`, which is referenced to `jobTitle` primary key column (`ID` or whatever)

Answer (score 0):

That's not a group by, but instead is a join.

In order to join, list all of the tables in the FROM clause, like this:

```
SELECT emp.empLName, job.jobTitle FROM tblEmployee emp, tblJob job
```

**NOTE** this won't do what you want though, as there needs to be a join condition on columns in the two tables.  As-is, this select will give output every job title once for every employee name.  For example, if there are 10 titles and 100 employees, you'll get 1000 results.

If the join column is called `id` in the `tblEmployee` table, and `emp_id` in the `tblJob` table, this is the full query to use:

```
SELECT emp.empLName, job.jobTitle FROM tblEmployee emp, tblJob job WHERE emp.id = job.emp_id
```

Note that `group by` is used to aggregate results.  For example, if a select returns 5 rows per employee and you want only 1 row with an average on one of the columns, `group by` is the tool to use.